# Write XSLT split with for each attributes

Tags: xslt

```
<Data>
     <value>APP_GoevrnerMasterDataSheets</value>
</Data>
```

I am trying to split using sslt with camelcase and - character.

I am trying to split like below
APP  _  Governer   Master  Data  Sheets

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried already?

Comment: Can you state whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0? Thanks!

Comment: Also please show the **exact** expected output.

Comment: I want to extract the data between the <Value> tag and my expected output is  to give sapce between the lower and upper case letter.  ie.  APP_ <space>Governer<space>Master<space>Data<space>sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replace function in **XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:template match="value">
   <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '([^A-Z])([A-Z])', '$1 $2')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output**

*`APP_ Goevrner Master Data Sheets`*